# Prove that $n(x^{1/n}-1)$ converges to $\ln(x)$.

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I would like to prove that $n(x^{1/n}-1) \rightarrow \ln(x)$ using the epsilon-N definition of convergence, or possibly the pinching theorem. I cannot use derivatives. I need a hint on how to get started.

Comment: As I said in your [other question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/997469) where this came up, I think the most intuitive way to think of it is that $x\mapsto n(x^{1/n}-1)$ and $x\mapsto (1+\frac xn)^n$ are inverse functions, so we kind of expect them to converge to inverse functions.  But I don't know how to formalize this without a lot of technicalities (e.g., to justify swapping limits).  If anyone can give a nice version of this argument, I'd like to see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume we know that $1+x\le e^x$.  Taking logs yields $\ln(1+x)\le x$, and so also
$$ \ln(1+x) = -\ln(\tfrac1{1+x}) = -\ln(1-\tfrac{x}{1+x})
\ge -(-\tfrac{x}{1+x}) = \tfrac{x}{1+x} $$
Thus
$$ \frac{x}{1+x} \le \ln(1+x) \le x $$
Replacing $x$ with $x^{1/n}-1$ yields
$$ \frac{x^{1/n}-1}{x^{1/n}} \le \ln(x^{1/n}) \le x^{1/n}-1 $$
Thus
$$ \ln(x) \le n(x^{1/n}-1) \le x^{1/n} \ln(x) $$
which yields the desired limit by squeezing.

Answer (score 2):

We have

$$x^{1/n}-1=\exp\left(\frac1n\ln x\right)-1\sim_\infty\frac1n\ln x$$

Comment: I'm not familiar with ~$_{\infty}$.

Answer (score 1):

Substitute $\;u=\frac1n\;$ , so that our limit is

$$\left.\lim_{u\to 0^+}\frac{x^u-1}u=:(x^u)'\right|_{u=0}=(\log x \cdot x^u)|_{u=0}=\log x$$

Comment: If you consider $x=e^y$, the computation is even more elementary.

Comment: Well, it is also a derivative...and if allowed, l'Hospital makes even simpler.