# What is $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n}{\ln(n)} (n^{1/n}-1)$?

Tags: limits

I'm having trouble evaluating this limit. Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n}{\ln(n)}\left(n^{1/n}-1\right)$$

I tried writing it in terms of an exponential with natural logs, but I couldn't manipulate the expression to anything useful.

Comment: Hint: $\exp(x)=1+x+o(x)$ when $x\to0$ hence $n^{1/n}=\exp(\ln n/n)=1+\ln n/n+o(\ln n/n)$.

Comment: Set  $h = \ln n/n$ for a moment. Can you rewrite the entire expression in terms of $h$? What happens to $h$ as $n \to \infty$?

Answer (score 1):

Note that the function $f(n)=n$ grows faster than $g(n)=\ln(n)$and when $n\to\infty$, we have $f(n)\gt\gt g(n)$. As such, we have,

$$\frac{g(n)}{f(n)}\to 0~\textrm{as }n\to\infty$$

Now, let $h=\dfrac{g(n)}{f(n)}$. Then, the limit (say $L$) becomes,

$$L=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{e^h-1}{h}$$

This is a very elementary limit which we know evaluates to $1$. You can verify that by using L'Hopital on the limit.

Comment: @Downvoter, Sorry for the typo earlier. I've fixed it now. You can remove your downvote. :)

Comment: You can't break the limit into two and say they both converge. limit(fg) not equals to limit (f) * limit(g).

Answer (score 1):

See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/998818) for a proof that
$$ \ln x \le n(x^{1/n}-1) \le x^{1/n}\ln x $$
Taking $x=n$ yields
$$ 1 \le \frac{n}{\ln n}(n^{1/n}-1) \le n^{1/n} $$
Now squeeze.