# How to prove this relation using the property of increasing & decreasing function?

Tags: calculus, inequality

> When $x > 0$ , show that $$x > \log(1 + x) > \dfrac{x}{1 + x} $$

Any hint will be appreciated.

Comment: What about the mean value theorem?

Comment: @Clement C: I do know mean value theorem but can tell more how to use it here?.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/998882 includes a proof of these inequalities.

Comment: For the second, let $f(x)=\log(1+x)-\frac{x}{1+x}$. Note that $f(0)=0$. We will show $f$ is increasing. We have $f'(x)=\frac{1}{1+x}-\frac{1}{(1+x)^2}\gt 0$ for $x\gt 0$, so $f$ is indeed increasing, and the result follows. The first inequality is done the same way, a little simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When $x = 0$, the three expressions are all equal to 0.

Differentiate $x - \log(1 + x)$, and show that this derivative is positive for all $x > 0$. This shows that $x$ grows faster than $\log(1 + x)$, and since they start from the same point, $x$ is always greater than $\log(1 + x)$.

The same method works for $\log(1 + x) > \frac{x}{1+x}$.

Answer (score 1):

Start here: 
$$x = \int_0^x dt > \int_0^x {dt\over 1 + t},$$
provided $x > 0$.

Answer (score 0):

i will use the fact that $\frac 1 x$ is decreasing on $(0, \infty).$ i will take $$ \ln(1+x) = \int_1^{1+x} \frac{dt}{t}, x > -1.$$

for $x > 0,$ we have 
$$ \frac1{1+x} < \frac1t < 1 \implies \frac{x}{1+x} < \ln(1+x) < x  $$

for $x > 0,$ we have 
$$ \frac1{1+x} > \frac1t > 1 \implies \frac{x}{1+x} < \ln(1+x) < x  $$

in both case we have $$\frac{x}{1+x} < \ln(1+x) < x, x > -1. $$

Comment: +1. Thanks, sir, your way has really let me to learn a new tehcnique to deal with these sort of questions:)

Answer (score 0):

All you need for both of these is
$$ e^y \geqslant 1+y, $$
which can be proven in a myriad of ways: binomial theorem, integration by parts, convexity, differential equations ...

First, putting $y=\log{(1+x)}$ gives
$$ 1+x \geqslant 1+\log{(1+x)}, $$
equivalent to one side. For the other, put $y=-\log{(1+x)}$, and then
$$ \frac{1}{1+x} \geqslant 1-\log{(1+x)}, $$
and rearranging gives the right inequality. In fact, we see that this works for $x>-1$, when we can no longer find $\log{(1+x)}$. Another way of writing the inequalities is
$$ x-1 \geqslant \log{x} \geqslant 1-\frac{1}{x}, \quad x > 0.  $$